# Vaadin pivot grid

Tags: pivot-table, vaadin, devexpress-gridcontrol

Does Vaadin have a pivot grid component? Not listed on their site.

I looked at something like
[devexpress](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/PivotGrid/Overview/React/Light/) but don't see something in Vaadin like that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official stock component in Vaadin that integrates pivot functionality yet. There are basically two approaches you want to explore.

1. If your dataset is large, it is better not to load the whole data to browser at once. Then you should do the pivoting in Java (or even in database level). There is example of doing pivot in Java [here](https://github.com/jcgueriaud1/nuveen-pivot-table). Just calculate the pivot result to list of HashMaps, and show that in regular Grid component.
2. If the dataset is small, then it is possible to do the pivoting in browser logic. There is one add-on in Vaadin's directory that does that, called [Pivot Table](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/pivottable-for-vaadin).

Comment: Tx! the data set is small and it has been preaggregated. I get an error when I try that pivot link but will research there. I am still wondering if i can use a react/js pivot component like devexpress in Vaadin. I tried to upvote but don't have enough pts.

Comment: "I am still wondering if i can use a react/js pivot component like devexpress in Vaadin. I", the Pivot Table add-on I linked is like that. Not using devexpress, but other library though of similar kind. Try it.